# sane-find-scanner could not open USB device ..... Access denied -- running Ubuntu 20.04 & 20.10

Tags: usb, permissions, scanner, sane

Using new installation of Ubuntu 20.04 and also trying Ubuntu 20.10
Attached scanning device is: Plustek OpticFilm 7600i

From what I had read about "sane-backends-1.0.29-670-gcf5c40b8e", I believe that this film/slide scanner is now supported.

$ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 07b3:0c3b Plustek, Inc. Film Scanner
...

$ scanimage -V
scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.29; backend version 1.0.29

$ sane-find-scanner
...
could not open USB device 0x07b3/0x0c3b at 001:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
...

using sudo, the command works
$ sudo sane-find-scanner
...
found USB scanner (vendor=0x07b3 [Plustek INC], product=0x0c3b [Film Scanner  ], chip=GL842) at libusb:001:003
...

When I use:
$ scanimage -L
No scanners were identified.

or

$ sudo scanimage -L
No scanners were identified.

I have been looking and reading various questions/answers and attempting what they indicate, but some of those Q&A apply to really old Ubuntu versions.

I even downloaded the trial software 'Vuescan' from 'Hamricks' site and it works fine scanning a 35mm slide, but it has the overlaid characters on the image.  So I would be forced to buy the $100 professional version to work with this Plustek scanner.

Maybe it is possible that the sane backend version that comes installed with Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10, even though it is v1.0.29, could be an earlier version than "sane-backends-1.0.29-670-gcf5c40b8e".

1) How do I check if "sane-backends-1.0.29-670-gcf5c40b8e" is the version in the Ubuntu 20.04 or 20.10?

2) Any suggestions on how to resolve the 'no scanners found' ... USB permissions problem?

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

2. Probably you must define a UDEV rule to add a permission for you if the scanner is plugged.
   Here you can find out how to set a rule of UDEV to add permissions for USB device:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713834/libusb-cannot-open-usb-device-permission-isse-netbeans-ubuntu

For example you can write a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/scanner.rules` with the following line:
`SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="07b3", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0c3b", GROUP="scanner"`

The rule above sets a `scanner` group for usb device file that represents your scanner. You must reload UDEV using
`sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`

You can verify the group and permission by checking:
`ls -l /dev/bus/usb/*/*` . Watch for a bus number and a device number of your scanner from `lsusb` . For details see https://wiki.debian.org/Scanner#perms .

Now you need to add users that should have access to the scanner to the `scanner` group. `sane-find-scanner` should work now.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to [$digital_infinity](https://askubuntu.com/users/558929/digital-infinity)'s answer:

If you check your rules with `ls -l /dev/bus/usb/*/*` and the output makes it seem like the permissions of the device were not affected by your udev rule:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /dev/bus/usb/*/*
crw-rw-r--  1 root root 189,   0 Mar  5 08:29 /dev/bus/usb/001/001
crw-rw-r--  1 root root 189,   1 Mar  5 08:29 /dev/bus/usb/001/002
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root root 189,   2 Mar  5 08:53 /dev/bus/usb/001/003
crw-rw-r--  1 root root 189, 128 Mar  5 08:29 /dev/bus/usb/002/001
```

https://wiki.debian.org/Scanner#perms explains this in further detail:

> Observe the + after the Unix permissions for /dev/bus/usb/005/067. It indicates an ACL (Access Control List) that specifies which users are granted access to/dev/bus/usb/005/067. To see an ACL, do

To check the detailed permissions of `/dev/bus/usb/001/003` use `getfacl /dev/bus/usb/001/003`.